# Unable to understand the error while uploading app to Google Play Store

Tags: android, release, google-play-console

I am getting the below error in app releases page in google play console when trying to release a new version of the app.

"INVALID_TRACK_FEEDBACK_MECHANISM: 4698157819833797777"

I am just receiving the above error without any further explanation. I have sent multiple emails to Google Play Support seeking further clarification but haven't received any response yet. Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: don't you have the chat with support option within google play console?

Comment: Yes we have used the chat option but they have asked us to wait.

Comment: I was asked to wait as well, but my issue was resolved by the end of day..

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the email address of an alpha/beta track tester is not valid, or when the feedback URL your provide for the testers is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We have checked both of them and made the changes accordingly but still receiving the same issue. Anything else we can try?

Comment: No, that's what this issue indicates. Maybe verify the other tracks as well, and make sure you commit all changes. Check for spaces or weird characters, ensure the URL is properly formatted... If after all this, it still doesn't work, reach out to the Play Console support.